# New Levels and Characters

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Has anyone noticed some new levels added by the developers? I've got like 6 but can't buy any of them. They are:
Service - Chiss Hsp
Recreational - Endor Adventure
Retail - Kashyyyk Shack
Residential - Endor Arms, Csilla Apts, Wookie Arms

Also, noticed a series of characters in the Album > Bitizens menu? They are categorised under Galactic Registry Series 1.

What do you guys reckon they are? Another Imperial Rewards game? Or just the usual Monday/Tuesday new levels?

Answer (score 1):

I also noticed the new levels, on iOS data 1.4.0.0.  The new levels are unbuildable as yet with the "No new levels of that type available for your amount of progress" message.  I suspect they are listed in preparation for a possible Monday rollout of new levels and I was happy to see some residential levels listed.

I noticed the new Bitizen category in the Album but I am not sure what to make of that.  Most of those were blank but there were a few with some descriptions (Baldarek, Shankeeka, and Tarffull.)  They have portraits and descriptions that appear when touched although their album pictures are still question-marked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

Got these new levels and characters pm Android too. Most likely this is content for next Monday (read Tuesday) update

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build one residential, one retail, and two empire levels.  I hurried construction of the residential, but was not able to purchase the next residential.  Maybe after all the other levels are finished construction I'll be able to add the other levels.

Answer (score -1):

The new ones are available here in Australia... no idea if elsewhere yet (but double check that the level type requested is what is shown at the top of your tower)

Edit: 90 or so mins later, the situation I had with level types has fixed itself... so yep, all are available to add now, but you can only do "a couple at a time"